# Number of Koch snowflakes when tiling Koch snowflakes next to each other

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractals

Imagine starting out with a Koch snowflake. You can stack 6 smaller snowflakes with 1/3 the area around the larger snowflake. After that, you can stack 18 even smaller snowflakes around those. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxdT5.png) represents what I'm trying to say. I was wondering if there was a formula for this sequence of how many Koch snowflakes are added on each iteration. OEIS has it as sequence [A330844](https://oeis.org/A330844), but they do not seem to provide a formula which is non-recursive. Is there a non-recursive formula? Just from graphing the numbers on a logarithmic plot, it seems to be some sort of exponential curve.

Comment: OEIS says $h_{n+1} - h_n = 6 \times $ [A077879](https://oeis.org/A077879), which has a closed form expression, though it's not very nice. So you could get it that way, though it's likely not very nice either.

Comment: I believe the h expression is only half the puzzle to get $a_n$. It also requires  $K_n$ which is only listed as some sort of necklace algorithm on OEIS.